# подключение Android studio

Tags: java, android

Как подключить vk java sdk(https://github.com/VKCOM/vk-java-sdk) к android studio ?

Comment: Там же все написано.

Comment: То чувство когда сам скинул ответ на свой вопрос... Но а вообще да, подробнее чем там описать трудно. Только готовое решение кинуть, дык и то там уже и такие есть

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну там же вроде как все описано.

- Подключаете зависимость в build.gradle

  ```
  dependencies {
       compile 'com.vk.api:sdk:LATEST_VERSION'
  }
  ```
- Инициализируете клиент где-нибудь в Application или в стартовой Activity в `onCreate()`

  ```
  TransportClient transportClient = new HttpTransportClient();
  VkApiClient vk = new VkApiClient(transportClient);
  ```
- Далеее авторизуетесь:

  Для юзера

  ```
    UserAuthResponse authResponse = vk.oAuth()
       .userAuthorizationCodeFlow(APP_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, REDIRECT_URI, code)
       .execute();

    UserActor actor = new UserActor(authResponse.getUserId(), authResponse.getAccessToken());
  ```

  Для групп

  ```
  GroupAuthGroupResponse authResponse = vk.oAuth()
      .groupAuthorizationCodeFlow(APP_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, REDIRECT_URI, code)
      .execute();

  GroupActor actor = new GroupActor(groupId, authResponse.getAccessTokens().get(groupId));
  ```

Все остальные подробности по вашей же [ссылке](https://github.com/VKCOM/vk-java-sdk). Там вон даже [примеры](https://github.com/VKCOM/vk-java-sdk/tree/master/examples) есть.

Comment: Здравствуйте, у меня появилось ещё несколько вопросов: 
1 .Папку src в папке sdk куда положить? (имею в виду как устанавливать)
2. В той ссылке есть пункт 2.Dependencies VK Java SDK uses: все что там нужно будет скачивать?
3. Проводить авторизацию можно и в onCreate() ?

Comment: Вам не нужно ничего никуда класть. Папка src это то что для вас создает сама студия. Там у вас и будет лежать проект. Вы просто прописываете зависимость в файле build.gradle и уже как я показал в коде инициализируете нужные классы